# How can I access my Log files in a running Spring Boot jar?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am basically using the default location `logging.path=logs` in my project folder. But, when I am compiling my jar and running it ... How can I access my log file.

Or is it generally a bad idea to save the log files there and better to choose different location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn’t the best place to save the logs to in reality, you shoud setup specific folder for log and then set up in the path of logging.path property

`logging.path = /path/to/folder/log`

logfile would then be named spring.log

> [Using logging.path] Writes spring.log to the specified directory. Names can ?be an exact location or relative to the current directory.

[Here](https://springframework.guru/using-logback-spring-boot/): is nice article about logging with springboot

Answer (score 2):

General Speaking，Set the log path out of `jar` for accessing and analyzing.